# Jquery: use URL as selector

Tags: jquery

I have a select box

```
<select id="be-variants-select" class="form-control" name="tx_cart_cart[beVariants][1]" required="">
   <option value="">Please choose ...</option>
   <option value="5" data-regular-price="16,95 €">40 x 40</option>
   <option value="6" data-regular-price="14,95 €" disabled="">60 x 30</option>
</select>
```

I append some text to an option value in some cases

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[disabled=""]','select.form-control').append(' - xxx');
})
```

The website has to languages with different URLs:

```
https://my-domain/.../
https://my-domain/de/.../
```

How do I have to extend the selector to get the opportunity for different appending text for the two languages?

Comment: get the url with `window.location.href` and then in an if/else block append different text depending on what the url is

Comment: I just want to check if '/de/' is included in the pathname and not the whole url because the urls can be different. I extended my question a little bit.

Comment: then use `window.location.pathname`, the same advice applies though, use the typical string manipulation methods to search the path for what you're looking for

Comment: You can use `if (window.location.href.search('/de/') > -1) {}`

Comment: Thanks, that's even shorter than my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a safer version

```js
$(function () {
  // replace the test url with window.location.href when you use the script
  var url = new URL('https://whatever/de/something') // new URL(window.location.href);
  var append = url.pathname.split('/').includes('de') ? "-xxx":"-yyy"
  $('[disabled=""]', 'select.form-control').append(append);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="be-variants-select" class="form-control" name="tx_cart_cart[beVariants][1]" required="">
   <option value="">Please choose ...</option>
   <option value="5" data-regular-price="16,95 €">40 x 40</option>
   <option value="6" data-regular-price="14,95 €" disabled="">60 x 30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't understand the 'something'. I have a lot of different urls to check so I don't know what I have to replace 'something' with.

Comment: Replace MY string used to test the code HERE with window.location.href!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found this solution. Thanks to @chiliNUT für his help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if(url.includes('/de/')) {
    ($('[disabled=""]', 'select.form-control').append(' - xxx'));
  }
  else {
    ($('[disabled=""]', 'select.form-control').append(' - yyy'));
  }
});
```